# Windows lock C Drive down show only certain folders

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have locked down C Drive via Group Policy using this method.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc975948.aspx
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978514.aspx

I need to only show a certain folders and allow users to only access this (Read/Write files only).

I have it locked down, but they still can create folders on the root of C Drive.

I've restricted what folders they can access, but at the moment when using an application they can click on the browse button and type in C:. Is there a way to show only the folder they are allowed to use.

I did try denying access to C Drive, even though they can access specified folders. This caused issues for the application running, any ideas on a better way to achieve this.

Folders they are allowed are below, with Read/Write access to files, but denied creation of folders.

C:\Program Files (x86)\App1
C:\Program Files (x86)\App2
C:\Program Files (x86)\App3
C:\App4

Comment: I think you probably created admin accounts, because standard users can't write into C: root

Comment: Within the applicatiom when they click on Browse, they can select C: and click 'New Folder' and name and delete it. These are standard user accounts. I will look further in to it.

Comment: @Taz8du29 Standard users have permission to create folders in the root of C: